# How to use session with @html.displayfor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, razor

Please I need help on how to get the generated I.d from a view using session in mvc...

```
@Html.Displayfor(m => m._consultation.consultid)
```

Assuming the value of the Consultid  is 1, I want to use session  to get that  I.D

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: Actually, m => m._consultation.consultid... is gotten from my strongly typed model... so I want to get the value of the consultid using session @pankaj

Comment: You can store that to session before passing to view,  inside controller action

Comment: For say your model is Employee And you're calling view like View(EmployeesObj) ; before that you can access the property of EmployeesObj and store to session. Like. HttpContext.current.session["id"]=EmployeesObj.I'd;

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to interact with session first within your controller.  Since this is usually where you have access to your data.  I am assuming that this `_consultation.consultid` value is simply a private member of your controller for this answer.

So in order to store in session it's really just as simple as adding to session within your controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    this.Session["ItemName"] = _consultation.consultid

    return View(new SampleViewModel());
}
```

Getting it out within your view is easy.  By default the session information should be accessible:

```
<h1>Hello Stranger @Session["ItemName"]</h1>
```

Keep in mind, this session data exists for the lifetime of the current browsing session.  Which means:

1. It will persist from request to request during the current browsing session, so it is important that this value is always updated when relevant.
2. If the user is logged back in some days later using a "remember me" cookie, it will no longer exist.  So it is important to not rely on this value always existing.

Just keep those in mind when developing your application.